# Python unit testing Beautiful Soup 4 - ResultSet. How to mock that?

Tags: python, unit-testing, beautifulsoup, pytest

I have a function that returns dict based on ResultSet from Beautiful Soup:

```
return {image["src"]: image["alt"] for image in images_data}
```

and i just have no idea how to test that.
My first idea was preparing a HTML document with images and expected data. Then I just compare expected data to returned dict:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
    def load_test_data(self):
        example_website = (
            Path(__file__).parent / "../tests/test_data/example_website.html"
        )
        with open(example_website, "r") as f:
            website_data = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "html.parser")
        return string_operations.prepare_src_and_alt(
            website_data.select("img.full-image")
        )

    expected_data_keys = ("string",)
    expected_data_values = ("another_string",)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ("img_src", "img_alt"), zip(expected_data_keys, expected_data_values)
    )
    def test_output_should_have_proper_data(self, load_test_data, img_src, img_alt):
        data = load_test_data
        assert data[img_src] == img_alt
```

I'm sure that is a bad way to do unit tests. Anyone had an idea how to properly mock ResultSet or make test data?

Answer (score 0):

From [the source code](https://tedboy.github.io/bs4_doc/_modules/bs4/element.html#ResultSet), `ResultSet` is just a `list` with an additional attribute.  Your code might not even use that "source" attribute:  Just set data to a list with the expected contents.  If you don't know what those contents look like, run BeautifulSoup against a dummy webpage like you show in the code, and `print` the `ResultSet`.

If you need the `source`, you can try setting that to a mock object of the appropriate type.

Comment: I was trying to do it before, but that list looks like:

`[<img alt="Alt" class="full-image" src="https://example.com/img/1mFjN19GzihJ9K21FoNbeuZGxLZJJQ2s.jpg"/>, <img alt="Alt2" class="full-image" src="https://example.com/img/6gOXbkxrkHMITAOiNdDsuWu14sIMihrM.jpeg"/>]`


And i've got syntax errors. If i read it from external file without bs4, it still doesn't work (`TypeError: string indices must be integers` from my function).